# Core Data - Importing Data (csv, xml)

Tags: swift, xml, csv, core-data, import

I'm relatively new in programming and i watched many courses about Swift and especially SwiftUI.
I came to a problem, that i couldn't solve yet and also googling and searching on here, couldn't really help me.

My problem:
Let's say, by default i setup Core-Data and created a new Entity called Bookentity with two properties 'title' of type String and 'author' of type String.
Is there a way, that i can import a set of Data (maybe csv or xml) into Xcode, which doesn't have to load every time the app is opened? Is there something like an import function in Xcode, that helps me to import a larger set of data?

I wrote an app where i programmatically imported a csv file, but everytime the app loads, the data will load again and that causes the app to stop for a couple of seconds. If i would use async-loading, the screen would be blanc.

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. What have you tried?

Comment: So when do you want to load it? Just on first install?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443936/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-load-a-large-csv-file-into-core-data) could be helpful